# How can I set breakpoints in an external JS script in Firebug

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I can easily set breakpoints in embedded JS functions, but I don't see any way of accessing external JS scripts via Firebug unless I happen to enter them during a debug session. Is there a way to do this without having to 'explore' my way into the script?

@Jason: This is a good point, but in my case I do not have easy access to the script. I am specifically talking about the client scripts which are invoked by the ASP.Net Validators that I would like to debug. I can access them during a debug session through entering the function calls, but I could not find a way to access them directly.

Comment: Sure thing - your specific title question, though, implies, in my mind, that you have access to the external file. Regardless, I think this page of information is good and will help anyone and everyone looking to do debugging of external JS files, whether in or out of their control. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To view and access external JavaScript files (*.js) from within Firebug:

1. Click on the 'Script' tab.
2. Click on the 'all' drop down in the
   upper left hand corner above the
   script code content window.
3. Select 'Show Static Scripts'.
4. Click on the dropdown button just to
   the right of what now says 'static'
   (By default, it should show the name
   of your current web page). You
   should now see a list of files
   associated with the current web page
   including any external JS files.
5. Select the JavaScript file you are
   interested in and it's code will
   display in the content window. From
   there, you should be able to set
   breakpoints as normal.

Answer (score 33):

Place `debugger;` in your external script file on the line you want to break on.

Comment: No problem. I am glad to hear that it has been useful to someone, that's the only reason I participate - helping people is fun and addictive! :)

Answer (score 4):

Putting the "debugger;" line also does the trick for the Chrome debugger.

Comment: According to the 3rd edition of the ECMA-262 standard (1999), which was looked-to for essentially 10 years, the `debugger` keyword was nothing more than a future reserved word. Now, according to the 5th edition (2009) of the standard (4th was not published), it is meant to be used by interpreters. I imagine all browsers worth their salt use it. I sure hope they do.

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on the line number in the left hand margin should create a break point for you (a red circle should appear).

All loaded scripts should be available from the firebug menu - click where it says the name of the current file should show a drop down with all files listed.

Answer (score 0):

After you place a break point in them, you can also call them by name in the firebug console, and see the output of (or step through) any intermediate functions.  This can help when the main entry point calls many other helper functions, and you are really just concerned with how these helpers are working.

That being said, I don't knwo anything about ASP.Net validators, so its possible this doesn't apply.