# Can Firebug set breakpoints in external JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is there any way in [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) to set a breakpoint in an external .js file that a page links to so that it can be stepped through?

(I suspect I've found a bug in jQuery and I want to be able to step through jQuery as it's handling events to see what it's doing.)

Comment: see duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633/how-can-i-set-breakpoints-in-an-external-js-script-in-firebug

Comment: hmm, how did I miss that?!? Voting to close (too late to delete it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question, but I don't think Firebug treats external javascript any differently than internal one. Just go to the "script" tab, select the .js file in the drop down list and set your breakpoint.

Comment: AHA! Completely missed that drop down. Thanks