# Can Not set BreakPoint in Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug-lite

I cannot set BreakPoint in Firebug script window in Chrome...

http://postimg.org/image/ivm2jss0d/

Similar Link :
[How can I set breakpoints in an external JS script in Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633/how-can-i-set-breakpoints-in-an-external-js-script-in-firebug)

[Can Firebug set breakpoints in external JavaScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579920/can-firebug-set-breakpoints-in-external-javascript-files?rq=1)

they suggest :

1.Click on the 'all' drop down in the upper left hand corner above the script code content window.
2.Select 'Show Static Scripts'.

I cannot find these options .. I can see only 1 drop down which has my script .

Another Suggestion.. Use debugger ;

Not working in my case

Please Suggest

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this

```
$('#button, #paragraph').click(function () {
debugger;
$(this).attr('value', 'Please wait');
});
```

Comment: Could you try Google Chrome to check if behaviour is similar?

Comment: try inserting console.log('log') into function, then if it gets printed out in console window click on the link to line put breakpoint and rerun the script.

Comment: Press the f12 button before click(you need to load the developer tool first inorder to hit the debugger)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: firebug opens on pressing f12

Comment: Could you create JSFiddle please. It sounds like script is not being executed.

Comment: Code is working fine in Browser .. I tried to run it on JSFiddle .it doesnt run.. i didnt use JSFiddle much .. just put HTML and Script in the sections ...

Comment: I just need to insert breakpoint .. i dont have any other issue